# Forever-monitor kill child with specific uid

Tags: javascript, node.js

I create new child node processes by

```
    var forever = require('forever-monitor'); 

    function startNodeProcess(envVariables, jsFileName, uid) {
      var child = new (forever.Monitor)(jsFileName, {
        'uid': uid,
        'env': envVariables,
        'minUptime': 2000
      });
      child.start();
    }
```

How can I implement a

```
function killNodeProcess(uid)
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out? @hari

Answer (score 0):

To kill a process you use process.kill(pid, [signal]) (see http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal)

You can get the pid from child.pid  (or the like, forever.Monitor might have it in a different place, but it does have it)

The trouble with killing a UID is that a UID is a user not a process, if you really want to do that see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/how-do-i-kill-all-a-users-processes-using-their-uid

Comment: Ah yes, the main trouble here seems to be finding the child that has the specific uid. I am not sure forever-monitor provides that functionality. I could maintain a mapping from uid to pid - but that causes other problems.